# How you make decision on a stock purchase after fundamental analysis?

Tags: stocks, stock-analysis, stock-markets

I am new to investing and just started practising on a simulator. I wrote a program on Matlab and to analyse various fundamental aspects of a company. These are the aspects computed my program,

A. Income statement

1. Revenue growth % (each year for last 5 yrs and each quarter for last 5 quarters)
2. Cost of revenue growth % (each year for last 5 yrs and each quarter for last 5 quarters)
3. Operating income growth % (each year for last 5 yrs and each quarter for last 5 quarters)
4. Net income growth % (each year for last 5 yrs and each quarter for last 5 quarters)
5. Total operating expense growth % (each year for last 5 yrs and each quarter for last 5 quarters)
6. Gross profit margin % (each year for last 5 yrs and each quarter for last 5 quarters)
7. Operating profit margin % (each year for last 5 yrs and each quarter for last 5 quarters)
8. Net profit margin % (each year for last 5 yrs and each quarter for last 5 quarters)

B. Balance sheet

1. Cash. Eq growth %   (each year for last 5 yrs and each quarter for last 5 quarters)
2. Longterm debt growth %   (each year for last 5 yrs and each quarter for last 5 quarters)
3. Total equity growth %   (each year for last 5 yrs and each quarter for last 5 quarters)
4. Working capital %   (each year for last 5 yrs and each quarter for last 5 quarters)
5. Total accounts receivable growth %   (each year for last 5 yrs and each quarter for last 5 quarters)
6. Total accounts payable %   (each year for last 5 yrs and each quarter for last 5 quarters)
7. Total inventory growth %   (each year for last 5 yrs and each quarter for last 5 quarters

C. cashflow Statement

1. High quality earnings growth %   (each year for last 5 yrs and each quarter for last 5 quarters
2. Free cashflow growth %   (each year for last 5 yrs and each quarter for last 5 quarters
3. Company lifespan growth %   (each year for last 5 yrs and each quarter for last 5 quarters

D. Discounted cash flow to determine if the stock is cheap (projected to 5 years)

So my question is with all these information and plots, how does one decide whether or not to invest in a company. Some of these aspects are positive for some companies and negative for some others. It is also worth noting that penalising a company just because of a few negative aspects are erroneous. I was thinking of a implementing a points systems to assist my decision. Any thoughts on this?

Answer (score 3):

The degrees to which a positive is positive and a negative is negative are up to you.  There is no correct answer.

A couple points of caution:

- You're never checking the company's market cap/share price or deriving what you deem to be a "fair value", only whether or not some data points have grown.
- It's not uncommon for one time charges to weigh on parts of a company's income statement or balance sheet.
- It's not uncommon for some part of a balance sheet/income statement to be recategorized
- Mergers, acquisitions and divestitures would also need a critical eye to determine they're impact to a company's finances and future prospects